# Facebook Messenger Chatbot Code - UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, facebook

Using the following code, I've setup a flask app:

https://gist.github.com/ugik/a218a599b1af0ea06b1b38e3a5132078#file-flaskfbmapi-ai-rig

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, request
import apiai

# FB messenger credentials
ACCESS_TOKEN = "EAAKsKOJ37rUBAKVZAQ21bn...UsZCXx6UWqQ6XuQr7OHnBYL3xD3Sy5u1ZAZCwip0XnTAHq25CsIpxRsbxZALRHOOguKm2unY7I06LRAZDZD"

# api.ai credentials
CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "78c0e0...d9404a2"
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def verify():
    # our endpoint echos back the 'hub.challenge' value specified when we setup the webhook
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == 'foo':
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200

    return 'Hello World (from Flask!)', 200

def reply(user_id, msg):
    data = {
        "recipient": {"id": user_id},
        "message": {"text": msg}
    }
    resp = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN, json=data)
    print(resp.content)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_incoming_messages():
    data = request.json
    sender = data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id']
    message = data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']

    # prepare API.ai request
    req = ai.text_request()
    req.lang = 'en'  # optional, default value equal 'en'
    req.query = message

    # get response from API.ai
    api_response = req.getresponse()
    responsestr = api_response.read().decode('utf-8')
    response_obj = json.loads(responsestr)
    if 'result' in response_obj:
        response = response_obj["result"]["fulfillment"]["speech"]
    reply(sender, response)

    return "ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, at line 51 there is an error in my server logs:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before
>   assignment

Which I understand the root of the cause is "response" is defined only within the if statement, however, since it is not my code, I'm having trouble defining the variable outside. Will this work if I place this code after line 48:

response = response_obj["result"]["fulfillment"]["speech"]